# Ordinary Least Squares with right hand size all zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

I have a system of equations $X\beta = 0$. The standard [Ordinary Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) solution to $y = X\beta$:

$$
\hat\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$

then only provides the trivial $\hat\beta = 0$ solution.

How can I compute a non-trivial solution?

Comment: Why would you want a non-trivial solution? Depending on the application you might search for the null space of $X$, or you might try to find a constrained solution for which $\beta$ has unit norm.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the solutions $\beta$ to $X\beta=0$ are organized in the *null space* of $X$. Furthermore, the dimension of $\operatorname{Null}(X)$ is $n-\operatorname{rank}(X)$ where $n$ is the number of columns of $X$. This means that $X\beta=0$ has no nontrivial solutions if and only if $X$ has *full column rank*.

Next,  matrix $X^\intercal X$ is called the [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of $X$. One important property of the Gramian is that is has the same rank a $X$, so $\operatorname{rank}(X^\intercal X)=\operatorname{rank}(X)$. This means that $X^\intercal X$ is nonsingular if and only if $X$ has *full column rank*.

Putting this together, we see that $X^\intercal X\hat{\beta}=0$ has nontrivial solutions precisely when $X\beta=0$ has nontrivial solutions. We only have $\hat{\beta}=(X^\intercal X)^{-1}X^\intercal y$ when $X$ has full column rank.